# How do I gain bonded object, as a magus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am open to a feat, item or perhaps a spell within my reach. I would be open to two feat cost, if the prereq feat is not completely useless.

So how do I gain bonded object, as a magus?

Comment: Can you please edit your question text to include your full question as well as context for the question? Inferring it from the title is nice, but if your question is, effectively, "See title" it's rather insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by way of the Ultimate Magic book.

First, you'll need to take Skill Focus (Knowledge). It can be any Knowledge skill, but you'll probably want to go with one you already have ranks in.

Once you have that, take the Eldritch Heritage (Arcane Bloodline). This requires 13 Charisma, the Skill Focus (Knowledge) you've already taken, and third level. You can now have a bonded object with all the benefits and drawbacks that that entails.

Comment: quite expensive, would eat my level 3 and 6 and also I have Charisma 9 :(

Comment: @Discipol You don't have to accept this answer straight away then. You can wait, or not accept one if none is satisfying. We regularly recommend people wait a day or two before accepting an answer to their questions, since the fact an answer hasn't been accepted yet adds an incentive for people to provide their own answers, giving you a greater variety of options to choose from. Picking one early, by contrast, can be a bit discouraging to potential answerers. If you're not happy with this answer, I recommend you leave it unaccepted for now. If you do go with it, you can always accept it later.

Comment: A quick note: Soul Forger Magus archetype gives you a weapon as a bonded item.

Comment: I have a Myrdamarch which is already a magus alternative, unfortunately, unless there are rules to combine the two! Can you have 2 alternatives at the same time as long as they modify different things?

Comment: Yes, as long as the abilities they replace are not the same, you can have two archetypes.